# How to compute mod hash of a field using JQ?

Tags: jq

```
{
  "a": "jdsdjhsandks"
}
```

How can I compute modular hash of `a` field using JQ expression?

Comment: The prospects of being able to "shell out" using the C implementation of jq are at best remote; but gojq is being actively maintained - you might like to chime in at https://github.com/itchyny/gojq/issues/101

Answer (score 1):

`jq` does not implement hash functions, you have to export the data, apply an external tool and re-import the hash.

For instance, if your JSON lived in a file called `input.json` and you were using `bash` to call `jq`, you could do:

```
# Export the data
data="$(jq -r '.a' input.json)"

# Apply an external tool
md5sum="$(printf '%.32s' "$(md5sum <<< "${data}")")"

# Re-import the hash
jq --arg md5sum "${md5sum}" '.a_md5 = $md5sum' input.json
```

or without using variables

```
jq --arg md5sum "$(
  printf '%.32s' "$(
    md5sum <<< "$(
      jq -r '.a' input.json
    )"
  )"
)" '.a_md5 = $md5sum' input.json
```

Comment: `md5sum` prints the hash value followed by the filename (or in this case `-` for stdin). `printf '%.32s'` extracts just the first 32 characters, not even a newline.

Comment: `md5` (where available) is more sensible ...